# Use `self` as a default parameter

Tags: swift, parameters

Can I use `self` as a default parameter in Swift? This code feels pretty straight forward but I don't understand the message the compiler is kicking back:

```
func printTree(node: TreeNode = self, tabs: String = "") {
  println(tabs + node.name!)
  node.children.forEach { printTree(node: $0, tabs: tabs+"\t") }
}
```

Error:

```
'TreeNode -> () -> TreeNode' is not convertible to 'TreeNode'
```

Huh?

There are probably other ways I could solve the tree traversal but I'm actually just curious about the default parameter restriction. Is this a real thing? Is there a mention of this in the docs? I couldn't find one.

**Update:**

I did this from scratch with no dependencies (I had a class heirarchy and a custom `forEach` monkey patch involved before). It still errors:

```
class PeanutButterJelly {
  var children: [PeanutButterJelly]?
  func doDance(){ println("dancing") }
  func everybodyDanceNow(pbj: PeanutButterJelly = self) {
    pbj.doDance()
    if let children = pbj.children {
      for child in children { child.doDance() }
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Swift compilation error: unresolved identifier 'self'
```

Xcode 6.3.2

Comment: eg: a solution that avoids the question: `func printTree(tabs: String = "") {
    println(tabs + "\(name)")
    children?.forEach { $0.printTree(tabs: tabs + "\t") }
  }`

Comment: The error must relate to your _implementation_, using `self` as a default parameter satisfies the compiler.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Can I use self as a default parameter in Swift

No. This is basically for the same reason that you can't say `self` when initializing an instance method:

```
class TreeNode {
    var otherNode : TreeNode = self // Use of unresolved identifier `self`
    func printTree(tree:TreeNode = self) { } // Use of unresolved identifier `self`
}
```

At the time you're *defining* this entity (property or method), there is no such thing as `self`. There will be a `self` later, when this method is *called*, inside the *body* of the function - because the function will be called on some instance, namely `self`.

One easy way to do what you want to do is to make this parameter an Optional with a `nil` default value. Then, in the body of the function, check for `nil` and use `self`:

```
class TreeNode {
    func printTree(tree:TreeNode? = nil) {
        let treeToPrint = tree ?? self
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Now it's legal to call `printTree` with no parameter, and it does what you want it to do:

```
TreeNode().printTree()
```

Comment: Oooo. Because it's parsed at *define* time... I wonder if I could use lazy evaulation/autoclosure in this case? Let me try it...

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `unresolved identifier 'self'` is the scope of one instance's implicit property `self`' is within every instance method. If you change the default value from self to children in your example you'll see error

> 'PeanutButterJelly.Type' does not have a member named 'children'

unlike in objc there is another version of self refer to the class's type there is no such thing is swift