# How to reference an attribute as a method default in a Swift class?

Tags: swift

Basically I have a class with the following code:

```
class Example
{

    let locale = Locale.current

    public init (locale: Locale = Locale.current)
    {
        self.locale = locale
    }

    public func GetFormatedString(date: Date,
                              formattingString: String,
                              locale: Locale = self.locale) -> String
    {
        let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
        dateFormat.dateFormat = formattingString
        return dateFormat.string(from: date)
    }
}
```

How can I reference the **locale** attribute as the default for the last parameter of **GetFormatedString()**.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Also related: [Use `self` as a default parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30798773/2976878)