# Use `self` as a default parameter on static/class methods

Tags: swift, function, methods

Is there a way to set self as a default parameter on static methods? For example

```
enum Foo {
    static func processSomething(forOwner owner: Any = self) -> Bar {
        ...
    }

    // or 
    static func processSomething(forOwner owner: Any = Caller.self) -> Bar {
        ...
    }
}
```

I found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30798773/5928180) but the question is about instance methods and I thought it might be possible for static/class methods because might be different.

This is so I can shorten codes like this for example

```
class Baz {
    var bar: Bar?

    func triggerSomething() {
        // automatically infer self instead of me explicitly placing it here
        // so the code will be this
        self.bar = Foo.processSomething()

        // instead of this
        self.bar = Foo.processSomething(forOwner: self)
    }
}
```

**Edit**: I'm actually just asking out of curiosity. I don't have a use case for this, and probably wouldn't use it in a real world scenario.

Comment: It's really useless to set a default value for argument `owner` when the type is `Any`. No matter what, you will always have to cast that owner to a `known type` inside this method.

Comment: That is true. I'm just curious about if using self as a default parameter is possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP agrees that there's little point in actually doing the thing he's asking about, and he hasn't offered a use case where it makes sense. I'm all for asking questions out of curiosity, but asking about pointless endeavors consumes resources that could be spent helping people with real problems.

Answer (score 2):

`self` as a reference to an instance isn't available to `static` functions, so the answer to your question is "no" as far as that specific way.  In the context however of saving yourself some typing, and by going through an instance method called `triggerSomething()` where `self` is available, you can accomplish what you're looking to do.

This answer is purely for the sake of addressing *how* you might go about doing this.  I should say I honestly think there isn't a lot of utility in it, and if you find yourself needing a pattern like this you'd probably be better off investing more time in your design.  But anyhoo, here's what this could look like.

Note that I'm returning an `Int` where you have `Bar` in your question for the sake of simplicity.

```
protocol Processable { }

class Foo: Processable {
    static func processSomething(forOwner owner: Processable) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func triggerSomething(forOwner owner: Processable? = nil) -> Int {
        return Foo.processSomething(forOwner: owner ?? self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question regarding my take on why I asked the question. But you are correct there really isn't a lot of utility in it. Using the code I added above, if possible, can have huge repercussions if used incorrectly. Crashes and bugs will surely appear.

Answer (score 1):

No. For a static function, there is no 'self' it can use.

I don't understand why you'd need it; you can remove the parameter and call self.processSomething or other.processSomething as appropriate. Maybe you should explain why you think it would be useful for your situation, and think if it makes sense.

Comment: Ok, so the answer is still no, and you're not saving a lot of code without the parameter. I still suspect there's a more elegant answer to what you're trying to do, but I can't know without knowing more. E.g., is it possible that the method you're trying to write shouldn't be on the enum at all, but on a base class/protocol that all potential callers should extend (so that you're not relying on an Any type)?

Comment: I'm actually just asking out of curiousity. I don't have a use case for this too and probably wouldn't use it in a real world scenario as it could cause confusion for other developers who work with me.